Fast Report TableDataSource
How can I add a TableDataSource to my dataset using FastReport? Why do I only have 3 options or do I need a license?
example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report ScriptLanguage="CSharp" ReportInfo.Created="06/20/2009 22:40:42" ReportInfo.Modified="05/24/2024 11:52:18" ReportInfo.CreatorVersion="2024.2.3.0">
  <Dictionary>
    <TableDataSource Name="Rel0" ReferenceName="Data.Rel0" DataType="System.String" Enabled="true">
      <Column Name="cd_grupo" DataType="System.String"/>
      <Column Name="nm_grupo" DataType="System.String"/>
    </TableDataSource>
  </Dictionary>
  <ReportPage Name="Page1" Watermark.Font="Arial, 60pt">
    <ReportTitleBand Name="ReportTitle2" Width="718.2" Height="37.8"/>
    <PageHeaderBand Name="PageHeader2" Top="41.8" Width="718.2" Height="28.35">
      <TextObject Name="Text1" Left="28.35" Width="94.5" Height="18.9" Text="cd_grupo" Font="Arial, 10pt"/>
      <TextObject Name="Text3" Left="132.3" Width="94.5" Height="18.9" Text="nm_grupo" Font="Arial, 10pt"/>
    </PageHeaderBand>
    <DataBand Name="Data2" Top="74.15" Width="718.2" Height="75.6" DataSource="Rel0">
      <TextObject Name="Text8" Left="28.35" Top="18.9" Width="94.5" Height="18.9" Text="[Rel0.cd_grupo]" Font="Arial, 10pt"/>
      <TextObject Name="Text9" Left="132.3" Top="18.9" Width="94.5" Height="18.9" Text="[Rel0.nm_grupo]" Font="Arial, 10pt"/>
    </DataBand>
    <PageFooterBand Name="PageFooter1" Top="153.75" Width="718.2" Height="18.9"/>
  </ReportPage>
</Report>


